# Android - Textview or Drawable generated and animated programmatically

Tags: android, layout, view

First off, I'm a beginner.  If this is way beyond the scope of a beginner's first application, just tell me.

The best way to explain what I want is as an example:  In Robo Defense, when you kill something, a little $10 pops up, animate translates/fades up about 5% of the screen and disappears. (almost like a toast, appears on top of canvas)

I'm looking for something similar to that same effect.  As a like, top-layer drawable that ignores the underlying defined XML layout.  I can handle the animation part of the code, but I'm curious as to how to create and inflate that view without wreaking chaos on my current layout.  If it would be easier as a drawable instead of text, thats really not a big problem for my project.  It is simply imformative, no interactivity at all, it will just be a quick little 500ms artifact to show that an action has occurred.

I could use a pointer in the right direction, or some similar code examples please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who is wondering, I ended up accomplishing this via wrapping my entire layout in RelativeLayout, making the appropriate changes necessary, then creating a TextView programmatically with layout_above, and then calling an Animation on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would create the TextView within your Java code, and then use an animation to make it rise and fade, once the animation has finished, destroy the TextView.
I've never done this before, but I think that should work!

Comment: Yep thats what I was thinking too, but I have no idea how to accomplish the "create" and "destroy" part of the plan.